# What is the fastest way to find out whether a question has been asked before?

Tags: support, search, duplicate-questions

I rarely have a lot of time to browse questions on these SE sites, and would therefore be delighted to learn of any new fast ways to research questions.

My present method is simply to type my question into the search window at the top of each Stack Exchange page, which seems to be a crude and imprecise way to search for similar questions.

Is there a more precise way to quickly search for questions in a Stack Exchange site?

Comment: to those wondering about why this sensible question (which additionally lead to [this wonderful answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238041/165773)) appears to be downvoted, most likely reason is that its [original version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/238030/1) didn't read well

Answer (score 18):

This may seem backwards, but if you want to know if a question has been asked before, **click 'Ask Question'.**

**One of the secret gems of our 'Ask Question' page** is that the duplicate-question search (before you actually submit your question) is way *way* better at finding if your question has been asked before than simply searching for keywords at the top of the page.

So click on 'Ask Question' > type in your question title, try a few variations, and see what comes up. You'll be surprised how easy it is to find questions that way.

> [image]

Comment: It's often even more effective than using a search engine.

Comment: And if you don't find it, and it turns out to be a duplicate, but the question is well-written anyway, you don't lose much from asking, and you get directed to the original question, so you don't stand to lose anything from trying.

Comment: On mobile platform?

Comment: @Brok3n nope, only in full site version.

Comment: An easy question come to my mind, the search api that is called when you Ask a question can’t replace the search box ´s one ? (while keeping full body search in option maybe)

Answer (score 7):

The *fastest* way is to type your question into the search field of your favorite search engine.

Search engines are built to search. They're very good at equating synonyms, ignoring "noise" words, and relating topics. And they're fast.

Even better, since Stack Overflow and the rest of Stack Exchange is such high-quality content, the questions and answers are generally indexed within *hours*, if not *minutes*.

It's not fool-proof, of course, especially when people don't agree on what terms to use.

And, don't forget, you can limit your search to a specific site/domain by using the `site:example.com` search operator. (Used by every search engine I know.)

If you want to stay within the domain of a Stack Exchange site, I'd simply start by clicking the "Ask Question" button, adding your question as the title, tagging appropriately, and seeing what comes up in the "Related" question list.

Comment: "If you want to stay within the domain of a Stack Exchange site, I'd simply start by clicking the 'Ask Question' button, . . ." Good suggestion. I'll try it.

Comment: The "related questions" list on the "ask question" page is way more effective than the search box.  (But if you don't know which SE site you want, you'll be better off with Google -- and starting with Google is never a *bad* move because SE's Google presence is quite good.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Not to mention basic research encourages you to google your question first anyway.