# Why does search for a question produce worse results than trying to ask a question when using stackoverflow?

Tags: support, search

For about a year now, I have done most of my SO searching using the "Ask Question" button rather than search bar.

Case in point, this question:

> How do I turn off this highlighting for HTML in PhpStorm?

Zero results in "search" but I found the answer in under a minute by "asking a question".

Anyone want to investigate and maybe improve the ordinary search tool? Not a big problem as I now know how to help myself if need be. I mostly arrive at SO having asked a general question in Google.

Comment: They really should just give up and integrate google's search into the site. the search has never been good at finding what we're looking for.

Comment: You may be interested in the existing discussion at [Related questions in “Ask Question” page is better than search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool) and [Is “Ask Question” a better search tool than the search bar in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307751/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Related questions in "Ask Question" page is better than search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool)

Comment: That's an old and absolutely amusing problem

Comment: People, people... the OP only asked this question so they could find the dupes...

Comment: _@BeNice_ I always get the best results when searching at Google (or DuckDuckGo if you prefer). At Google you can also use the site feature to restrict the results for a specific SE site.

Comment: @:canon - harsh much. To be honest it wasn't a "problem" for me I just wanted to post a comment. And, don't shout, I din't even search for a similar question. I just wanted to SHOUT in the hope that someone might listen - all in the interest of the greater good mind you. But now I am feeling that I have been bad. Sorry. Feel free to close this/delete this.

Comment: @:canon got your comment re me being meta but then it disappeared (as topic closed probably) but I up voted your comment as it cheered me up. Here is hoping you see this even though the query is now closed.

Comment: The answers on the 11-year-old post are pretty much outdated, inaccurate, and sorely lacking in  solutions. I would, if I could, reopen this in the hope of receiving up-to-date and  superior answers  while closing the older post as a "duplicate", or better yet, for being "ignored and overlooked"

Comment: @BeNice As a side note, on MSE when relating to Stack Overflow, you can tag your question with [tag:stack-overflow] and leave "on Stack Overflow" out of the title. I should have edited that into your question with my first edit, my apologies.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Amusing? Just imagine how much time that will have cost humankind, by using an effectively suboptimal search and not improving it. Okay, people probably learned to use Google but still.

Comment: @Trilarion I've been complaining about this... almost as long as I've been an SE user. At this point... yes, its amusing  :D

Comment: [Google search is very much broken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48AOOynnmqU) at this point. It doesn't take much first-hand experience to realise. It will not return canonicals (with high quality answers) from 2008 and 2009. The typical search result is an inadequate result from 2015 with a low-quality question and one or two low-quality answers.